# Dynamic Conditional Formatting With VBA Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I'm fairly new to VBA. I want to conditionally format the cells of the column of the ActiveCell so that they are highlighted blue if they are not present in the column which is 4 columns to the right of the ActiveCell. I recorded a macro which performed this for one particular set of columns but I am having trouble changing it so that it works for arbitrary sets of columns based on the position of the ActiveCell. The recorded code is given below

```
    Range("Y8").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=COUNTIF(AC:AC, Y8)=0"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 15773696
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=0
```

Could anyone please tell me how to alter this so that Y8 is the ActiveCell and AC:AC is the column 4 columns to the right of the ActiveCell. Thank you.

Comment: `... := "=COUNTIF(" & ActiveCell.offset(0,4).entirecolumn.address(false,false) & " , " & Activecell.address(false,false) & ")=0"`

Comment: @TimWilliams here is a great place to use R1C1 type references. They will be automatically converted by Excel so you actually don't need to get the addresses at all. Simply try `"=COUNTIF(C[4], R[]C[])=0"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a VBA solution then use R1C1 references in your posted code for the COUNTIF bit like:

`"=COUNTIF(C[4], R[]C[])=0"`

These are relative references and Excel will automatically work out and convert them into the right A1 style references for you.

Alternatively,
If the sole purpose of your macro is to get those cells coloured then you don't need a macro for this.

Select your data in the first column with cell A1 as the active cell within your selection (I call it column A below, and the 4 column offset as column E) and go to Conditional Formatting.

Add a new 'conditional format based on a formula'

Type in as the formula

=ISERROR(MATCH(A1,E:E,0))

And then choose your desired format.

Note that as the cell references are relative, you can very easily copy and paste the format to any arbitrary column and it will still check to 4 columns to the right of the new column.